# swi-prolog: how to open readline interaction

Tags: swi-prolog

**env:**

- windows 7 32bit
- swi-prolog 6.2.6

Is swi-prolog support readline interaction?
[[manual]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27B.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/readline.html%27%29%29) says it support GNU readline, how to open on windows 7?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to recompile [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org) with readlin.
SWI-Prolog distributions for Windows available from their site are not linked with it.

You can check your environment issuing this query:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(readline, X).
```

which in my case (SWI on windows 7) yields `X = false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  
My stuff is `X = false` too.

Comment: @gusbro: If it yields "false" then we can use "readline" predicate on Windows 7, isn't it? :(

Comment: If it yields 'false' it means that SWI was not compiled with readlin library, so you'd better recompile it with it to use "readline"